# Characterization of locally free sheaf of rank 1 (invertible sheaf)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Is it true that Any locally free sheaf of rank 1 over X is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_X (n)$ for some $n\in \mathbb N$

Answer (score 3):

What is $X$? Perhaps projective with ample line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$? The answer is yes when $X$ is the projective space, but of course it fails for most other projective varieties, the Picard group can be quite different from $\mathbb{Z}$.